# Access is denied. Check credentials and try again., The process failed to get the correct properties

Tags: oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I'm having issue with one of my Microsoft Graph Token.

When I debug it, I can see in the JSON Web Token Payload that the token is indeed for the Microsoft Graph API `aud = https://graph.microsoft.com` and it seems I have the appropriate scopes `scp = Mail.ReadWrite Mail.Send User.Read`.

Though when retrieving an email using `GET https://graph.microsoft.com/1.0/me/messages/<ID_HERE>` or trying to create a new one `POST https://graph.microsoft.com/1.0/me/messages` I get the following error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "ErrorAccessDenied",
    "message": "Access is denied. Check credentials and try again., The process failed to get the correct properties.",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "---",
      "date": "---"
    }
  }
}
```

I'm not sure how I could fix this. Any help appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Are you able to access the Exchange Online mailbox using Outlook for the web (https://outlook.office365.com)?

Comment: I don't know, this is not my account I don't have the password.

Comment: I'd suggest asking the user. It's possible they don't have a mailbox or it isn't hosted in an accessible location.

Comment: We were able to request the OAuth scopes though. I'll ask and report back.

Comment: First clue: were are subscribed to mailbox push notifications and we did receive 4 emails already.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you use get-rolegroupmember "organization management" cmdlet to check if your administrator has the organization management permission.

If your administrator doesn't have the permission, I recommend you use add-rolegroupmember cmdlet to add your administrator to this group to check the result. Also, you can check with a user that has the same permission as this person to see if you get a result and if the problem is on your end or the user's end.